# per-file dependencies in ant

Tags: ant, dependencies

I have a set of input files, each of which is processed to generate an output file.  In one case it's hibernate xml files as input, and java files as output, but that isn't the only case I have to deal with.

In make, I would have set up a rule to tell it how to generate a .java file from an .hbm.xml file (modulo the .hbm.xml specifying a different class name to generate), and modifying a single .hbm.xml files would trigger the build of a single .java file.

How do I express the dependencies in ant so it will only build the out of date .java files and not all of them just because one .hbm.xml changed?

I'm looking at `apply` and `up-to-date`, but not seeing a solution yet...

Comment: So each time in your build you are generating a new .java file for each .hbx.xml file, and because Ant sees the change timestamps as new the build is triggered for all .java files.  Is this correct?

Comment: That happens too, but the first step is to only generate the .java files that need to be; I don't want the build doing more than it must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [ant-contrib outofdate task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/outofdate.html)?

The example at the end of the doc looks like something you could use:

```
  <outofdate property="manual.outofdate"
             outputsources="grammer.sources">
    <sourcefiles>
      <fileset dir="${src.grammer}" includes="**/*.y"/>
    </sourcefiles>
    <mapper type="glob" dir="${src.grammer}" from="*.y" to="${gen.grammer}/*.c"/>
    <mapper type="glob" dir="${src.grammer}" from="*.y" to="${gen.grammer}/*.h"/>
    <sequential>
      <shellscript shell="bash">
        cd ${gen.grammer}
        for g in ${grammer.sources}
        do
            gengrammer $g
        done
      </shellscript>
    </sequential>
  </outofdate>
```

Also note that you might use [ant-contrib "for" task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) in the body of the `outofdate` task.

To initialize ant-contrib do this:

```
<property name="ant-contrib.jar" location="..."/>
<taskdef
  resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"
  uri="http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net"
>
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${ant-contrib.jar}"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if a sub-set of the sources are out of date, then the property named by `outputsources` is set to a list of _just those sources_ and not all of the sources, correct?

Comment: Correct, `outputsources` lists only sources newer than respective targets.